# What is the standard practice for REST-API Authorization tools in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication, rest, laravel-api

what you recommended for a large scale project. 
there are many solutions to that like laravel API authentication, JWT, OAuth etc.
what would be the standard solution for large scale laravel API ?

this API will be integrated with Reactjs

Comment: Just a sidenote: JWT is a token format, OAuth is a protocol . They are not alternatives and in fact there are OAuth 2.0 implementations out there that use JWT as a bearer token.

Comment: thanks,
im planning to use JWT for authorization